# How to set default value of select box with non-existed value in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-options, jquery-selectbox

Maybe this can has duplicated or maybe there's a way to solve this,

but I couldn't find any way to solve this.

So please don't be angry with my silly question and give me some information or way to solve this.

Please see this fiddle.

[Set default value of select box](https://jsfiddle.net/Canet/xo2rLfek/1/)

What I want is, when I get array from `http call`,

how to set default value of select box with the value which is not in array.

I've used `ng-init` but it didn't work.

I know there are other ways to solve this like using `<options>` tag and put first value of option or

using `selected` but I want to use `ng-options`.

No matter what you give is a link, doc, or something, it'll be great help to me.

I'll wait for your any comments or answers. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First solution you can add one more **option** tag for default value

Html Code

```
<div ng-app="MyApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <select ng-options="opt as opt for opt in testOpt"
                data-ng-model="resultOpt"
                data-ng-change="checkResultOpt(resultOpt)">
        <option value=''>Choose Category </option>
        </select>

    </div>
</div>
```

Controller Code

```
 var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp', [])
.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.testOpt = [
        'ID',
        'Name',
        'Email',
        'Address'
    ];
    $scope.resultOpt = '';
}]);
```

Working [code](https://jsfiddle.net/xo2rLfek/9/)

Second Solution : you just add one more item in your array list after get from http call

Html Code

```
<div ng-app="MyApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <select ng-options="opt as opt for opt in testOpt"
                data-ng-model="resultOpt"
                data-ng-change="checkResultOpt(resultOpt)">
        </select>

    </div>
</div>
```

Controller Code :

```
var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp', [])
.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.testOpt = [
        'ID',
        'Name',
        'Email',
        'Address'
    ];
    $scope.testOpt.splice(0, 0, 'Choose Category');
    $scope.resultOpt = 'Choose Category';
}]);
```

Working [Code](https://jsfiddle.net/xo2rLfek/10/)

hope this will help you

Comment: Your fiddle looks almost near to my purpose. What I really want is when I select a category, default value have to disappear. But thank you for give me some hints!